# duplicating stdin to check the end

Tags: linux, bash, unix, openssl

I need to call openssl from a binary, I wrote xml text in a popen( ) call to a script embedding openssl

I get a problem if my binary fails during writing, openssl ends succesfully to write my file, but when I decode I get a truncated file.

I would like to check at the end of openssl call if the received stream ends with "< /myEndTag>"

Context: my binary must never write a file not encrypted, I would like not to openssl decode

here is an example, to illustrate (thanks to comments, this is not a valid statement, just a way to make you get an idea):

```
echo "blablaf foo bar" | openssl -out file.crypt | grep -E "bar$"
```

then, if grep has found "bar$", my file.crypt is good

Comment: can you provide a code example and a workflow diagram please ? It is very hard to understand what you need.

Comment: you are right, I added a sample

Comment: One would hope that `openssl` would be writing to a temp file, and only atomically renaming it to `file.crypt` once it has successfully finished the write.

Comment: yes, checking the end of the stdin is my condition to rename the encrypted file and it goes to somewhere else

Comment: why not working with the return-code of openssl command ? if $? is 0 then openssl command ended successful

Comment: `echo "blablaf foo bar" | openssl -out file.crypt` results in an usage error. Please show your code. Since Stack Overflow hides the Close reason from you: *Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution fitting my needs:

my script now use a tee to tail before openssl

```
tee >(tail -n2 > ${checkfile} ) | /usr/bin/openssl enc -aes-256-cbc -out ${outfile} -e -K ${KEY} -iv ${KEYOPTION}
```

grepping my end xml tag in the checkfile which only contains 2 lines is secure enough.

As I mentionned, checking openssl return code is not enough since I write to openssl via a popen statement.

If my binary hangs while he is writing, it seems the streams goes to openssl, which find his end, no matter if it's the real end or a broken stream. openssl finely make a valid encrypted output file with the truncated content.